# "message": "The user does not belong to any Dasher customer.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }

Tags: google-vault-api

```
error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The user does not belong to any Dasher customer.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" while hitting Google Vault API to GET Matter List
```

The request that I am sending looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:ActivityInput xmlns:ns0="tibco.com/namespaces/tnt/plugins/json">
   <URI>vault.googleapis.com/v1/matters</URI>
   <ns0avascript:Parameters>
      <Query />
      <Header>
         <Authorization>Bearer ya29.c.ElqmBrzx2cYzdY4fzcq_N6nsbPg0CUYH0DBBhyaxVsqSZBP3482yBXXJRZIrV_PZuWgGsc3sJyWapCJQaqEeLMNWpHbbHhTqWqEl800d9FvTcSyFYFLBrWZEiSM</Authorization>
         <Content-Type>application/json</Content-Type>
      </Header>
      <Body>
         <Text />
      </Body>
   </ns0:Parameters>
</ns0:ActivityInput>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Request what I am sending looks like: 
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<ns0:ActivityInput xmlns:ns0 = "http://www.tibco.com/namespaces/tnt/plugins/json">
 <URI>https://vault.googleapis.com/v1/matters</URI>
 <ns0:Parameters>
  <Query/>
  <Header>
   <Authorization>Bearer ya29.c.ElqmBrzx2cYzdY4fzcq_N6nsbPg0CUYH0DBBhyaxVsqSZBP3482yBXXJRZIrV_PZuWgGsc3sJyWapCJQaqEeLMNWpHbbHhTqWqEl800d9FvTcSyFYFLBrWZEiSM</Authorization>
   <Content-Type>application/json</Content-Type>
  </Header>
  <Body>
   <Text/>
  </Body>
 </ns0:Parameters>
</ns0:ActivityInput>

Comment: What am I missing here??

Comment: See [ask]. Try to keep everything in one place with an [edit] to the question where you explain what you are trying to do, show your [mcve] and show the results. If this is not about coding, maybe researching over on https://superuser.com/ or other SE site might be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the Google Vault API requires a GSuite account with admin access to Vault. Make sure that the account you did the Oauth with also has access to Vault capabilities at

https://ediscovery.google.com